# Cannot run web application because Tomcat cannot open stacktrace.log

Tags: tomcat, grails

I deployed a Grails web application using the Tomcat manager. It wouldn't start. I looked up the error and linked it to an error opening "stacktrace.log". I searched for errors on "stacktrace.log" and found an open Jira bug report/ticket on the Grails webpage.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2730

(not) Conveniently, it's unresolved and there is no fix version.

Supposedly, the log4j configuration is in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy. All of the log4j  stuff in my Config.groovy is commented out.

What's the quickest way (minimal configuration file editing) to disable stack trace logging?

If there are any configuration files in particular that I should post, just request them. I'd post all of my Tomcat and Grails config files, but there may be a lot of them and I don't know where all of the configuration files are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just point the log file to a directory that the user that runs tomcat was write permission. See this post from the jira issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2730?focusedCommentId=48061&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-48061

This should work (supposing that you have exported a war file from grails and published it trough tomcat, therefore you are in production environment)

```
environments {
    development {
        log4j.appender.'errors.File'="stacktrace.log"
    }
    production {
        log4j.appender.'errors.File'="/var/log/myapp/stacktrace.log"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also see this answer for a different configuration http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4376?focusedCommentId=50985&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-50985

Comment: Which file do I put that in? I've seen that solution, just didn't know where it goes.

Comment: Config.groovy. That should reside in grails-app/conf folder of your application

Comment: Is /var/log normally write-protected? If so, is there a directory I can point it to that is always public?

Comment: Yes, /var/log is used for system logging. You can try /tmp if you dont really need to permanently store logs (cleared at every reboot) but i dont think that's a good idea. Just create a directory somewhere (for example under /home/), make the user that runs tomcat owner and give write permissions For example if user that runs tomcat is tomcat that belongs to a group tomcat (you can see the group by typing id <username>)  mkdir /home/tomcat/logs; chown tomcat:tomcat /home/tomcat/logs;chmod 700 /home/tomcat/logs

Comment: I'm getting another log4j error. How do I tell Tomcat to run in a "safe mode" where any non-essential functionality is disabled? log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No signature o
f method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.call() is applicable for argument types: (org
.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger) values: [org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger@40f6a33b]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), max(gro
ovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)